# How to use only part of a POST value based on conditional

Tags: php

I currently have a PDO script that contains a POST variable that can be either:

`RU11223344992 PS:1201012` OR `RU11223344992`

If the value is like `RU11223344992 PS:1201012` the script should interpret it by taking all values to the left of `PS:1201012` leaving only `RU11223344992`

If the value is like `RU11223344992` it should interpret it just the way it is.

Depending on this conditional, the value will be assigned to the variable `PostValue`.

UPDATE:

Using the suggested solution I getting the response `Array` when doing echo `$data`

```
$input = $_POST['postvalue'];

if (strpos($input, "PS: ")) 
{
 $data = explode($input, "PS: ");
}
else{
 $data = $input;
}
echo $data;
```

Comment: Well it's a string, so you can use any of the [PHP String Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) on the `$_POST['form-input-name']` value

Comment: Can you not check the size of the string and make sure you only ever use the first 13 characters?

Comment: @lukas No it will not always be 13 characters, but it will always be anything before PS: Can you please show an example of how I can essentially trim the rest of the string value?

Comment: This might help along the way https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366748/2232127

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to verify if there's a `PS:` on your input? Then you can [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) it to get the first part (before space) of the string.

```php
$input = $_POST["form-input-name"]
if (strpos($input, " PS:")){
    $data = explode(" PS:", $input)[0];
}
else{
    $data = $input;
}
```

Comment: It will safer to take any value before PS: can something like that be done?

Comment: Yeah, I eddited it to looks more like a answer :) @Martin

Comment: @SebLason yeah, you can change `" "` by `"PS: "`

Comment: Please see my updated post, I cannot seem to get the right response when there is a `PS: `  echo `$data`  just print `Array`

Comment: Sorry @SebLason I missed the right handling of the array explosion. It should work now.